# Permitir upload de pdf laravel

Tags: laravel

Preciso permitir upload de pdf, como faço? veja o validação

```
public $rules = array(
    'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf|unique:images,local,NULL,id,type,upload'
);
```

eu acrescentei `pdf` mas não funcionou, não fez o upload?

Comment: algum erro é mostrado?

Comment: talvez são pdf's convertidos que estão com o mime-type diferente, provavelmente como octet-stream. Adicione esse à sua lista de mimes

Comment: Não mostra erro, só não faz o uplod